# AWS: sort all emr (Elastic MapReduce) jobflows based on its terminated time in python boto

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto, emr

One easy question for gurus, but I just cannot figure it out:

I'm using boto python API, the relevant code is:

**terminatedjobflows = emr_connection.decribe_jobflows(states=["TERMINATED"], created_after = created_after)


sorted(terminatedjobflows, key=attrgetter('created_after'), reverse=True)**

What I wanted to do is just to sort all terminated jobflows reversely so that I could get the most recently terminated jobflow.

But once I run my code, it keeps complaining:
ERROR: 'JobFlow' object has no attribute 'created_after'

Also, I tried using 'enddatetime' to replace 'created_after', didn't work either.

Any help please?

Comment: I think the attribute you are looking for is ``creationdatetime``.

Comment: @garnaat great! It works now. Could you post your answer so I can accept it? Thanks!

Comment: OK, but it didn't actually help with my case: since what I wanted to sort all those jobflows based on its terminated time, instead of its creationdatetime, do you know how to do this please? Thanks

Comment: ``enddatetime`` would be the correct attribute.  But you say this isn't working for you?

Comment: yes, it works just now. weirdly. It didn't work before. So now, another problem: I cannot access the first element of jobflows, I thought it's a list, but jobflows[0] didn't work: ERROR: 'JobFlow' object is not iterable